# Not sending Transaction mail

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, transactional-mail

I try to add Transaction mail but i am not getting any mail

```
$template_id = 'my_custom_email';
    // Who were sending to...
    $email_to = 'mymail@gmail.com';
    $customer_name   = $name;
    // Load our template by template_id
    $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);

    $custom_variable = 'my custom variable for my custom eamil template';
    // Here is where we can define custom variables to go in our email template!
    $email_template_variables = array(
        'custom_variable' => $custom_variable
        // Other variables for our email template.
    );

    // In my case I am using the Store Name as sender name here.
    $sender_name = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_STORE_STORE_NAME);
    // In my case I am using the general store contact here as the sender email.
    $sender_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
    $email_template->setSenderName($sender_name);
    $email_template->setSenderEmail($sender_email); 

    //Send the email!
    $email_template->send($email_to, $customer_name, $email_template_variables);
```

**Config.xml**

```
<template>
            <email>

                <my_custom_email>
                    <label>Custom email</label>
                    <file>custome_email.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </my_custom_email>
            </email>
        </template>
```

**custome_email.html**

```
<!--@subject My custom email template @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",
"var logo_alt":"Email Logo Image Alt",
"var data.custom_variable":"Custom variable"}
@-->

<!--@styles
body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
@-->

<body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
                    <!-- [ header starts here] -->
                    <table bgcolor="FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                        <!-- [ Header starts here] -->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <a href="{{store url=""}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" border="0"/></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- [ Header ends here] -->
                        <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"">This is my custom email template</h1>
                                <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 8px 0;"><strong>My custom variable is :</strong> {{var custom_variable}}</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- [middle ends here]-->
                        <!-- [Footer content starts here] -->
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA; text-align:center;"><center><p style="font-size:12px; margin:0;">Thank you again, <strong>{{var store.getFrontendName()}}</strong></p></center></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- [Footer content ends here] -->
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

what's wrong on this

Comment: fir check `<template>` is inside the `<global>` tag and check admin panel  email template  is listed or not..

Comment: In side global tag only i add this code existing module is it any pronlem

Comment: no that is not problem the email defined inside the global tag check that it is inside or not?

Comment: It's inside global tag only also path this is the path of html file app/locale/en_US/template/email/my_custom_email.html

Comment: go admin panel in `system-> transactional email`  and add new check in dropdown your template is listed or not

Comment: No it's not showing

Comment: Now it's showing While load a template it shows empty

Comment: can you email template file paths?

Comment: Sorry i am not getting

Comment: email template file path

Comment: in config.xml  <file>custome_email.html</file> and Files app/locale/en_US/template/email/my_custom_email.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your template file name is not correct

change this

```
<file>custome_email.html</file>
```

to

```
<file>my_custom_email.html</file>
```

Comment: Now i am not getting mail

Comment: load in admin panel  it is working

Comment: ya in admin panel its working.

Comment: I don't know why i am getting two time mail

Comment: How to get COntact number here any idea

Comment: which contact number?

Comment: Customer Contact Number

Comment: it is for after login user?

Comment: Yes But information in billing address only

Comment: Can you please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122837/custom-email-template-not-working